# Bootstrap formValidation error clearing using reset button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to reset the bootstrap form by clearing all the validation errors using a reset button, but, with no success. I have used formValidation plugin.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){
var validator = $('#forms').bootstrapValidator({  
fields : {
//all validation for form-flields done here  
  });
});
</script>
```

This is my html form code-snippet:

```
<form id="forms" method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="#">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="firtsname" class="col-md-2 control-label">First Name:</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" maxlength="35" placeholder="Enter First Name" required autofocus>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                      </div>
```

There are 6 more  for different form fields. The 6th group contains the buttons, which is like this:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                           <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
                                <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                                <button type="reset" id="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
                            </div>
                      </div>
                </form>
```

I wish to use the reset button inside the "forms" to reset the errors generating from the bootstrap validator plug-in.

Comment: @T-Heron I have posted the code snippet above in the query of mine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jquery Validation plugin, then try this:

```
var validator = $( "#myform" ).validate();
validator.resetForm();
```

Put this code inside the click block of reset button, it will reset all the error messages.

[Reference](https://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.resetForm/)